# Copy portion of the page in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have this web application that generates this nicely formatted table (bootstrap type). I would like to have a button that when clicked it copies the table in the clipboard so the user can paste it in word/excel.

I have tried several libraries like: ng2-clipboard, angx-clipboard but they all allow to just copies values from input fields and not portion of page. I tried to create the table's html dinamically in the service but it doesn't keep the styling and in word it ends up just pasting the html piece of code.

I have this snippet that used to work on the old version of the application, I think it selects the table and then calls the copy command:

```
this.selectElementContents = function (el) {
    el = document.getElementById('filtered-table');
    var body = document.body, range, sel;
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        range = document.createRange();
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        try {
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        } catch (e) {
            range.selectNode(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    } else if (body.createTextRange) {
        range = body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
    }
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

This does not seem to be correct "angular" way to do things, how should I proceed?